# Unreachable rules in the Java 8 CFG?

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

Maybe a rather in-depth question but does anybody has an idea why in

> The Java LanguageSpecification - Java SE 8 Edition (2014-03-03)

which defines the formal context-free grammar of Java 8 in terms of production rules and terminals not all defined rules are reachable?

The Specification describes dozens of rules such as

> IfThenStatement:
>   if ( Expression ) Statement

or

> AssertStatement:
>   assert Expression ;
>   assert Expression : Expression ;

which all make perfect sense.

But strangely some of the defined rules are not reachable by others such as the important rule

> Type:
>   PrimitiveType
>   ReferenceType

In total I counted the following 2 rules that where not reachable by others:

1. PackageName
2. Type

How could one define a complete Java 8 CFG with having unreachable rules?

Comment: Hm... I don't see what you mean. As far as I can see, for example
`SingleStaticImportDeclaration` is reachable from `ImportDeclaration` which is reachable from `CompilationUnit`. Am I missing something? :)

Comment: Hi @JoachimIsaksson .. indeed I had some typos in my parser and 4 out of the 6 rules are reachable :) BUT still I cannot see how 'PackageName' and 'Type' are being reached. Can you help?

Answer (score 6):

Often specification authors find it convenient to formulate rules of the spec in terms of non-terminals; sometimes, however, some of the useful non-terminals are not, for technical reasons, used in the main grammar.  In such cases the spec sometimes defines the relevant non-terminals anyway, to ground some of the rules of the spec in the grammatical formalism.

Here, for example, the rule for Type sends a pretty clear signal that all types are either primitive types or reference types.  But the grammar has a number of places where only primitive types may be referenced, and others where reference types are required.  If Type is not reachable, it need not mean that the syntactic grammar is incomplete; it may only mean that in fact there are no places in the syntactic grammar where the authors found it useful to refer to Type.  The non-terminal Type may nonetheless be defined, if the spec authors find it a useful tool of exposition.

In specs which appear in multiple versions, another reason sometimes arises:  a non-terminal ceases to be used in the main grammar, but an appropriate definition for it is given to avoid breaking any other specs which refer to that non-terminal, and to allow those other specs to upgrade gracefully to the new version of the spec containing the grammar.

I do not know which of these reasons applies in the case of these non-terminals in Java 8, or whether there is perhaps some other reason.